# How do I find functions which satisfy this symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis

I want to find functions with all the following symmetries:

(1) $f(x,y,z)$ is cyclic i.e. $f(x,y,z)=f(y,z,x)=f(z,x,y)$.

(2) $\overline{f}(x,y,z) = f(z,y,x)$ Reversed order is complex conjugate.

(3) $g(x,y,a,b) \equiv \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y,z)f(z,a,b) dz = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(b,x,z)f(z,y,a) dz$. i.e. $g(x,y,a,b)$ is cyclic.

(4) $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x,y,z)|^2 dx dy dz=1$

So far I have only found $f(x,y,z) = b e^{-c(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$ for certain constants $b$ and $c$.

Is there a general method to find such functions? In particular are there any that **can't** be factored i.e. $f(x,y,z)\neq h(x)h(y)h(z)$?

Comment: What does $f^*$ mean?

Comment: Complex conjugate. I changed it to $\overline{f}$

Comment: (1),(3) can you precise cyclicity, is it only for one shift to the left, or does $f(z,x,y)$ need to be considered too, because for $g$ it is shifting to the right? for (2) you mean $\bar f(x,y,z)=f(z,y,x)$ ?

Comment: If it works for one shift it works for all shifts.

Comment: Thx for editing, the question is clear now. Doesn't mean it is easy to answer though :o.

Comment: Is $f\in \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ or $\Bbb{R}[x,y,z]$? Do you want any $f$ that satisfies $(1)-(4)$ or a different $f$ for each case is OK?

In particular, (2) and (4) confuse me, you want a complex conjugate, and also real integration?

Comment: f can be a complex function of real variables. e.g. f(x,y,z)=x+y+iz. Or alternatively f can just be real.

Comment: It seems to me that the expression $\sum_i b_i \exp(-c_i(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))$ always satisfies (1)-(3) so it's just a matter of taking coefficients $b_i$ such that (4) is satisfied. This gives you a large family of radial functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution:

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\pi^{3/2}} e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)} (1 + 4(xy+yz+xz) )$$

Satisfies all including:

$$g(x,y,a,b) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y,z)f(z,a,b) dz = \frac{(1+4(xy+xa+xb+ya+yb+ab)+16xyab)e^{-x^2-y^2-a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{2}\pi^{5/2}}$$ is obviously cyclic.

It's not the most interesting answer since it is too symmetric because it is not only cyclic but invariant under any permutations of variables.